# Issue with AES encryption different result in Java app runing in 2 servers (2 JVMs)?

Tags: java, encryption, jvm, aes

my code generates two different values for the same target text in two differents servers,

this is my code :

```
private static Key generateKey() throws Exception {
    MessageDigest digester = MessageDigest.getInstance("MD5");
    digester.update(String.valueOf(keyValue).getBytes("UTF-8"));
    Key key = new SecretKeySpec(digester.digest(), "AES");
    return key;
}
```

encrypt code :

```
    Key key = generateKey();
    Cipher c = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding");
    c.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, key);
```

if you have any ideas, thanks in advance

Comment: Your code _implicitly_ generates a random IV every time you encrypt, so that each time a different ciphertext results (which you can retrieve with `Cipher#getIV()` after initialization) . You can use `IvParameterSpec` to _explicitly_ specify an IV yourself in `Cipher#init()` with the 3rd parameter, then the _same_ ciphertext is generated for the _same_ IV (same key and plaintext assumed). In practice, however, for security reasons a new (randomly generated) IV must be used for each encryption.

Comment: Asked the other way around: **why** do you think that encrypting the same text twice should produce the same output? Did you just assume that, or do you actually require that to be the case?

Comment: Thank you very much @Topaco, i will try with your proposition :)

Comment: to explain more my situation we have a java application runing on production side with 2 servers (2 JVMs), the used encryption functionality encrypts and decrypt the file path (in file system) and get as a result an ID for each file used in interface to download the file (link/file=CRYPTED_ID), when we display the generated file ID for the same file from 2 browsers (first request the server 1 and the second request the server 2) we got two differents values

Comment: One more remark on the role of the IV for _decryption_: You need the IV (whether implicitly or explicitly generated) for decryption. For this, the IV (which is no secret) is sent to the recipient along with the ciphertext. Usually, IV and ciphertext are concatenated on binary level. The recipient separates both and can then perform the decryption. By the way, MD5 is insecure as a key derivation function.

Comment: It seems you are confusing encryption with hashing. It’s not the purpose of encryption to produce IDs.

Comment: Thank you @Holger for your reply, can you please share with me a link to an example of hashing implementation, thanks in advance

Comment: @Holger in my case i need to use a two way solution which is encryption because we encryptes the file path and we send it to an external system, and then this information is used by the external system to download the file (after decryption), sorry for my english :D

Comment: But then, it doesn’t matter when the encryption result looks different. It only matters whether you can decrypt correctly.